# React - Array in state is updating, but only first object in array is being rendered to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, rest

I am trying to create a web app with the PokeAPI.

My goal is to load a bunch of pokemon from their type. Currently, I've hardcoded my API URL to only retrieve fire type pokemon. However, when I try to render these pokemon to the screen with an array, only the first fire pokemon gets rendered ([reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZlZ0.png)).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PokemonRow from './PokemonRow.js'
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {rows: []};
    this.performSearch()
  }

  performSearch() {
    var pokemonRows = [];
    const urlString = "http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/type/fire/";
    $.ajax({
      url: urlString,
      success: (searchResults) => {
        console.log("Fetched Data Succesfully");
        console.log(searchResults);

        const pokemonOfType = searchResults.pokemon;



        pokemonOfType.forEach(pokemon => {
          //console.log(pokemon.pokemon.name);
          const pokemonURL = pokemon.pokemon.url;
          $.ajax({
            url: pokemonURL,
            success: (pokemonFromArray) => {
              console.log(pokemonFromArray);
              let pokemonObject = <PokemonRow key={pokemonFromArray.id} pokemon={pokemonFromArray} />;
              //console.log(pokemonObject);
              pokemonRows.push(pokemonObject);
              console.log("pokemonRows.length: " + pokemonRows.length);
              this.setState({
                rows: pokemonRows
              })
              console.log("this.state.rows.length: " + this.state.rows.length);
            }
          })


          //console.log(pokemonRows);
        })
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error("Failed to fetch data");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table className = "titleBar">
          <tb>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img width="50" src="pokemon.png" alt="Pokemon logo"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                Pokemon Information
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tb>
        </table>

        <input className = "searchBar" placeholder="Enter Pokemon Name" />
        {this.state.rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react'

class PokemonRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table key={this.props.pokemon.id}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {this.props.pokemon.name}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img alt="pokemon_image" width="120" src={this.props.pokemon.sprites.front_default} />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h3>Stats</h3>
              <p>Height: {this.props.pokemon.height} ft</p>
              <p>Weight: {this.props.pokemon.weight} lbs</p>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );

  }
}

export default PokemonRow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over the array:

```
this.state.rows.map(function(row) {
  return row
})
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. When i hard coded a rows array before, I didn't need to loop over it. Do i need to loop over it now because it's constantly being updated?

Comment: Every time you call `this.setState({...})` the component gets re-rendered, so the loop will run again and display the new data.